# Важен ли английский язык программисту?

Tags: работа

● Нужен ли английский язык в жизни в целом и программисту в частности?
● Если да, то для чего?
● И, наконец, как посоветуете учить?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нужен ли он вообще в жизни, думаю, вопрос неуместный в силу своей очевидности. Нужен ли они программисту? Разумеется. Хотим мы этого или нет, но большая часть фундаментальных трудов по любым отраслям компьютерных наук написана на загнивающем западе. Разумеется, на языке Шекспира. Крупнейшие IT компании мира работают в США (все эти гуглы, майкрософты, ораклы и прочие).   А они, между прочим, двигали и двигают всю нашу отрасль вперед. В эту же кучу можно собрать и программистскую литературу, документацию, форумы (да-да, я про stackoverflow) - все это выходит и публикуется на английском гораздо больше, чем на любом другом языке. Все популярные языки программирования, как это нетрудно заметить, базируются на англоязычных лексемах (это тоже говорит о многом)

Ну и еще один мальенкий, но красноречивый пример. Многим, наверное, известна замечательная компания JetBrains. Она выпускает отличные IDE, пилит свой язык и делает немало других хороших вещей, например, мимимишный Решарпер. Так вот основана эта компания дорогими россиянами - С. Дмитриевым, Е. Беляевым и В. Кипятковым, один из ее главных офисов находится в Петербурге, и работают в ней отечественные программисты. Однако  вы не найдете официальной русскоязычной документации для их продуктов. Там всё на сами понимаете каком языке. Законы рынка, знаете ли.

Если вы знаете английский хотя бы немного, то вы можете найти ответ на свой вопрос гораздо быстрее. Если вы знаете английский хотя бы немного больше, чем "совсем немного", то вы можете пользоваться английской документацией к библиотекам, sdk и прочим штукам. Если вы знаете английский более-менее сносно, вы можете читать соответствующую литературу не ожидая того замечательного момента, когда она будет переведена на русский. Особенно учитывая тот факт, что иногда качество перевода хромает. И еще более особенно учитывая тот факт, что иногда перевода нет вообще. 
Если вы знаете английский хорошо, то и вовсе можете работать на проклятых капиталистов хоть удаленно, хоть переехать в их логово и разорять их оттуда изнутри.

Что касается "как учить" - желательно с хорошим репетитором, который будет заниматься с вами индивидуально. Если такой возможности нет, то очень неплохим  способом считается просмотр фильмов с субтитрами (русская озвучка-английские субтитры или наоборот). Ну и всякие там учебники никто не отменял. Хотя самое главное при изучении английского - это регулярность занятий и постоянная практика - навыки имеют свойство стираться из памяти, если их не тренировать. Ну и напоследок один весьма неплохой сайт для этих богоугодных дел. [Вот он](http://lingualeo.com)

Answer (score 3):

> Нужен ли английский язык в жизни в целом и программисту в частности?

В жизни в целом - вы, наверное, не против попутешествовать.
Программисту в частности - да, нормальная документация (а не примеры в интернете) существует только для проектов-мастодонтов. Для python, например, оригинальная документация существует только на английском (хотя существуют русскоязычные материалы в довольно хорошо оформленном виде, а не "как сложить два плюс два в магическом языке питон"). По Phalcon, например, на русском полноценной документации не найти.
В конце концов, есть stackoverflow, где фактически образовано не просто лучшее коммьюнити по стране, а по миру вообще. Как только вам нужны какие-то тонкости, приходится лезть либо очень глубоко в документацию, либо в комментарии к коду, либо в сам код, либо на SO. Можно вообще напрямую спросить разработчика того или иного фреймворка.
Без всего это можно жить и продолжать кодить по примерам из интернета, но специалистом без подробного изучения возможностей довольно сложно, и тут уж как повезет со сферой, в которой надо быть специалистом - если PHP или C#, то там есть практически вся необходимая документация и большое количество русскоязычных разработчиков, сидящих на тематических сайтах, но если вы решили взяться за что покруче, например, хаскелл - тут без вариантов.

> И, наконец, как посоветуете учить?

Я пользуюсь ресурсом lingualeo.com. Но лучше всего, конечно, в живом общении.